# React async data in useEffect doesnt trigger render

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous

I have the following state  `const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);`

and I'm trying to fetch some initial data using `useEffect` ->

```
useEffect(() => {
   const init = async () => {
     const newList = await getArticlesIntoDOM();
     setArticles(newList);
   };

   init();
 }, []);
```

To check if the data is correct, I'm rendering it using simple HTML `<h1>{JSON.stringify(articles)}</h1>`

My problem is:

- if `getArticlesIntoDOM` contains only 1 API call, it works fine
- if i have multiple API calls inside this method, I'm not getting the data rendered.

Example of code that fails:

```
const getArticlesIntoDOM = async () => {
    const articles = [];

    posts.forEach(async (post) => {
      const user = await getUserById(post.userId);
      const comments = await getCommentsByPostId(post.id);
      const imageUrl =
        "https://picsum.photos/1280/720?random=" + getRandom(300);

      articles.push({
        postId: post.id,
        title: post.title,
        author: user.name,
        imageUrl: imageUrl,
        comments: comments,
      });
    });

    return articles;
  };
```

the state is changed but the render is not triggered. I made another button that `console.log` the current state and the data is correct but it is never outputted in the `<h1>`

!!!! I found a solution -> If i use a simple for loop instead of foreach everything is working as expected

Answer (score 0):

The UseEffect is triggered when the value in the brackets changing , when you put bracket empty the Useeffect trigger when the component rendered.

I suggest you to try to put another useEffect like that :

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(articles)
}, [articles])
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, `articles` is an object and you are trying to render it in h1, wont render. You have to use, map function to render it

```
....
articles.map((post) => {
 
  return (
    <h1> {post.author} </h1>

)
}

    ....
```

Now you can render each data inside like that